# Ruby on Rails testing - NameError: uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the following errors when trying to run tests:

Using Rails 3.2.1

$ rake test
Run options:

## Running tests:

EEEEEEEEEE

Finished tests in 0.012787s, 782.0346 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

1) Error:
test_user_entry_no_email(UserTest):
NameError: uninitialized constant UserTest::Users
    /home/nowobil1/projectDresser/test/unit/user_test.rb:12:in `block in '

2) Error:
test_user_entry_no_username(UserTest):
NameError: uninitialized constant UserTest::Users
    /home/nowobil1/projectDresser/test/unit/user_test.rb:18:in `block in '

3) Error:
test_valid_user_entry,_only_username_and_email(UserTest):
NameError: uninitialized constant UserTest::Users
    /home/nowobil1/projectDresser/test/unit/user_test.rb:5:in `block in '

3 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 3 errors, 0 skips

Here is my test file:

```
    1 require 'test_helper'¬                                                                                                                                    
    2 ¬
    3 class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase¬
    4    test "valid user entry, only username and email" do¬
    5       user = Users.new¬
    6       user.username = "testUser1"¬
    7       user.email = "testEmail@mail1.com"¬
    8       assert user.save, "Saved a valid user entry"¬
    9    end¬
   10 ¬
   11   test "user entry no email" do¬
   12       user = Users.new¬
   13       user.username = "testUser2"¬
   14       assert !user.save, "Saved a user without email"¬
   15   end¬
   16 ¬
   17   test "user entry no username" do¬
   18       user = Users.new¬
   19       user.email = "noUsername@email.com"¬
   20       assert !user.save, "Saved a user without username"¬
   21   end¬
   22 end¬
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on conventional naming, your model will be named `User`, not `Users` (however, your table is named users).

Try replacing `Users` with `User` on lines 5, 12, and 18.

Answer (score 0):

Use **User** instead of Users in your tests pls.